# remove an element completely from page with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive WordPress theme and i wanted to remove a `div` element in the sidebar which has the class `hide` from the page with JQuery when the document width is smaller than 768 pixels.
What JQuery code should I use?

Comment: Any specific reason you don't want to do this using CSS?

Comment: i cannot use media queries because by using css media queries , the element will only be hide but we cannot completely remove it from the markup ?

Comment: You say "remove". Does that mean that if you resize the window to 500px then back up to 1000px you don't want the removed elements to come back?

Comment: As far as I know if it's hidden or removed doesn't change how the page is displayed

Comment: @Hussain you do not want to completely remove it from the DOM for the reason I specified in my answer. `display: none` is what you want to use for the specific screen resolution.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use jQuery to remove an element in a responsive design. In your case, if the user was browsing on desktop and temporarily made the window small the element would disappear. Then if the window was made large again the element would not re-appear.

A better solution is to use a CSS media query to hide the element by setting `display: none` for the lower resolution:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    #foo { 
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$(".hide").each(function(){
  if($(document).width() < 768){
   $(this).remove();
  }
})
```

Comment: I have used this code but when i am resizing the browser less than 768px, the div with "hide" class is not removing . it is present there as usual

Comment: then you have to bind a handler on window resize. use $(window).resize(function(){ ... }) and put the above code inside.

Comment: it worked but will it work on the devices (like tablet or mobile) which are of less than 768px width ????

Comment: I have tested in html and it worked but when i am placing the code in my wordpress website , it is not working on resizing window ?
What should i do ?

Comment: There can be some other script overriding this script.. and please make sure jquery is loaded properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if($(document).width() < 768){
      $('.hide').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better done with CSS but if you really want Jquery you can use the `resize()` event on the `body` and `.hide()` (which will make it as if it wasn't there) and `.show()` (to bring it back when the window is big enough) on the stuff to be hidden.

```
$("body").resize(function () {
    if ($(this).width() < 768)
    {
        $(".hide").hide();
    }
    // Code is below for making .hide come back. 
    else {
        $(".hide").show();
    }
});
```

If you just want the element to be totally removed when you resize below 768 pixels you can use:

```
$("body").resize(function () {
    if ($(this).width() < 768)
    {
        $(".hide").hide();
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$("body").resize(function () {
    if ($(this).width() < 768)
    {
        $(".hide").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: do the element deleted from page when hide function runs or it only hides the element and the element is still present on page ?

Comment: @Hussain I've updated my answer to show how you can either ````hide()```` or ````remove()```` but I don't see why it makes a difference to you. It would be cleaner to just hide and from the user's perspective it should look no different.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use jQuery (or JavaScript at all) for this. Instead you can use CSS and Media Queries.

```
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    .hide {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```